# Why does the <C-n> syntax for using control key work with :command command but not with :normal command?

Tags: vim

I am trying to execute a normal mode command `Ctrl-n` or `j` from Ex mode. Normally, one would do this  using the `:normal` command. For example, the following command moves the cursor one line down.

```
:normal j
```

So does the following command. Note: `^N` is typed by pressing `Ctrl-v Ctrl-n`.

```
:normal ^N
```

But the following command does not work. This command seems to have no effect on the buffer.

```
:normal <C-n>
```

However, when I create a new Ex command for `Ctrl-n` using the following command, it works!

```
:command Down <C-n>
```

Even this works, although `normal` is redundant here.

```
:command Down normal <C-n>
```

Now, I can use the Ex command `:Down` to move the cursor one line down.

My question is why does the `<C-n>` syntax not work with the `:normal` command but works with the `:command` command?

Comment: In what sense does `:command Down <C-n>` work?  When I try that and then `:Down`, I get an error message.  Have you already defined a `:cmap` or `:map!` for `<C-N>`?

Comment: @benjifisher It works in the sense that when I enter `:Down`, the cursor moves one line down. I have not defined `:cmap` or `:map!` for `<C-N>`. What is the error message that you get?

Comment: After `:command Down <C-n>` and then `:Down` I get the error message `E492: Not an editor command: ^N`.  I am still using vim 7.3, so perhaps this works in 7.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `:exec` and escape the `<c-x>`:

for example:

```
:exec "normal \<c-n>"
```

in fact the instruction you can find in `:h :normal` help doc:

```
to use |:execute|, which uses an
expression as argument.  This allows the use of
printable characters to represent special characters.

                        Example: >
                                :exe "normal \<c-w>\<c-w>"
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question is probably academic (or you are trying to solve another problem) but, for what it's worth, you can already do `:+` and `:join`.